# How do you compare multiple properties of objects within an ArrayList using the Comparable Interface?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compareto

I need to sort `Rectangle` objects in my ArrayList `list1` by their corresponding properties: `height`,`width`, and `topCorner`(Point).
I am able to sort the list when evaluating one property.

How can I set up my `compareTo` method so that it first attempts to sort the objects in the list by `height`, then by `width`(if all object heights are equal), and finally by`topCorner`(if all object heights and widths are equal)?

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

private int x;
private int y;

public Point(){
    this(0,0);
}
public Point(int x,int y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
public int compareTo(Point pt){
    if(x==pt.x){
        return y-pt.y;
    }
    else{
        return x-pt.x;
    }
}
public String toString(){
    return "("+x+", "+y+")";
}
}
class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {

private int height;
private int width;
private Point topCorner;

public Rectangle(int x,int y,int height,int width){
    this.height=height;
    this.width=width;
    this.topCorner=new Point(x,y);
}
public int getHeight(){
    return height;
}
public int getWidth(){
    return width;
}
public Point getPoint(){
    return topCorner;
}
public int compareTo(Rectangle rect){
    if(height!=rect.height){
        int compareHeight=((Rectangle)rect).getHeight();
        return this.height-compareHeight;
    }
    else if(width!=rect.width){
        int compareWidth=((Rectangle)rect).getWidth();
        return this.width-compareWidth;
    }
    else if(topCorner!=rect.topCorner){
        Point comparePoint=((Rectangle)rect).getPoint();
        return this.topCorner-topCorner;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("// ERROR BRO // ERROR BRO //");
    }
    return 0;
}
public String toString(){
    return "(H:"+height+", W:"+width+", P:"+topCorner+")";
}
}
```

===========================================================================

```
public class RectangleComparable {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Random rn=new Random(21);
    ArrayList<Rectangle> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int index=0;index<10;index++){
        int ran1=rn.nextInt(21), ran2=rn.nextInt(21),
                ran3=rn.nextInt(21), ran4=rn.nextInt(21);
        list1.add((new Rectangle(5,ran2,ran3,ran4)));
    }
    System.out.println("KEY : H=height, W=width, P=point\n");
    System.out.println("Unsorted List : \n"+list1+"\n");
    Collections.sort(list1);
    System.out.println("Sorted List : \n"+list1);
}
}
```

I'll go ahead and apologize if this is somehow a duplicate question. I looked around, but I didn't find anything that gave me a really direct answer (because I'm still a programming noob).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `Comparator` or build one as follows:

```
Comparator
    .comparingInt(Rectangle::getHeight)
    .thenComparingInt(Rectangle::getWidth)
    .thenComparing(Rectangle::getTopCorner);
```